# Source code (java and C++) browser/viewer for my website

Tags: java, c++, browser, software-distribution, documentviewer

I want to include a code browser in my portafolio so pelople can navegate though my projects source code (C++ and Java mainly) without having to download anything.

Note that I want it to be inside my server hosting.

I have been trying to find something with Google but I only get results for HTML source browser and/or local browsers.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is completely off-topic.  It is programming related in the sense that he'd like people to be able to view his code.  There have been other accepted questions of a similar nature here.

Comment: I just want to find a php/html library or whatever that allows me to do that. That is not programming related ? Please someone explain me why this is offtopic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at hosting a GitLab server on your own domain.  It is similar to GitHub.  More [here](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq).

Comment: I saw this before but I only need a browser. I do not need pelople to contribute or develop the code further. Thanks anyway for trying to help. If I do not find anything else I will have either to code it myself or use GitLab (or similar).

Comment: YOu can setup GitLab to only have read permissions.  If you're looking for a very simple approach, you can also look at browser interfaces for CVS - there are quite a few.

Comment: I will have a look to GitLab in detail :) Thanks for the response.

Comment: GitList is also great and simpler

Comment: Finally I will use this [link](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/php-file-tree/)